# SQL parse error, command prompt not showing expected output

Tags: mysql, sql

It is my first time setting up a MySQL and I am having some trouble making it operate. I have a WAMP server downloaded first of all, and I am trying to use vs code to write queries. I downloaded an extension from the vs code marketplace to use sql in the editor. I wrote some queries but they don't always work. I was able to make a table, but when I used show database or show tables, they didn't work and the output only returned ER_PARSE_ERROR and said I have an error in my syntax.

Here are the queries I wrote that didn't work:

```
show tables;
show databases;
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? These are not the same thing.

Comment: I meant MySQL, just updated my question

Comment: Not sure, instead you can use mysqlworkbench , for DB Tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just now I have installed the plugin and able to connect the database and able to run your queries it's working fine.

[image: Working image]

Still you can choose the language as sql as shown in the below  picture and try, it will work.

[image: Solution]

Comment: It works now. I was writing queries in the mysql section after when I click the database icon on the side, and when I did that in the explorer section, it worked.